# How to Select Component from Folder with iron-pages

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to load page view resources from a nested folder, but am having trouble getting the resources.

How can I direct `iron-pages` to get `app/shop-home` instead of `shop-home`?

```
<iron-pages role="main" 
            selected="[[page]]" 
            attr-for-selected="name" 
            selected-attribute="visible" 
            fallback-selection="404">
  <shop-home name="home"></shop-home>
  <shop-cart name="cart"></shop-cart>
  <shop-404-warning name="404"></shop-404-warning>
</iron-pages>
```

`iron-pages` is located in the `shop-app` element, and the home, cart, and 404 views are all located in the root of the `src` folder.

```
- src
-- shop-app
-- shop-home
-- shop-cart
-- shop-404-warning
```

This loads fine when developing on localhost, but ultimately I would like to host the application on Windows IIS as `ip-address/app` and am having problems configuring the get requests because IIS in hijacking the routing.

Comment: Do you want to load `app/shop-home.html` instead of `shop-home.html` ? that your code is points the first ? how you load. Please add your js code how you are trying to load.

Comment: I updated the question.  Hopefully it is clear...

Comment: If you're deploying to `domain/app` on IIS try setting the `base href` to that route in `index.html`

Comment: This works, but produces a new set of issues...

Comment: The main page doesn't load until I enter the ```domain``` URL after ```domain/app``` is loaded.  The routes aren't staying in sync with page views.